Behavior of quadratic form on basis
Let $V$ be a vector space. My notes define a quadratic form on $V$ to be a function $q : V \to \mathbb F$ such that

$q(\lambda v) = \lambda^2 q(v)$ for any $\lambda \in \mathbb F$ and $v\in V$.
the map $\psi_q(u,v) := q(u+v)-q(u)-q(v)$ is bilinear (and symmetric).

It goes on to state that if we define a basis $\mathcal B = \{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ for $V$, then $q$ behaves as
$$ q\left( \sum_{i=1}^n c_i v_i \right) = \sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}c_ic_j,  $$
where $a_{ij}$ is the $(ij)$-entry of the matrix representation $[\psi_q]_{\mathcal B}$.
This seems incorrect. Indeed, in trying to prove this, we obtain (using summation convention)
$$ c_ic_j \psi(v_i,v_j) = \psi(v_ic_i, v_jc_j) = q(v_ic_i+v_jc_j)-q(v_ic_i)-q(v_ic_i) = q(2v_ic_i) - 2q(v_ic_i) = 2q(v_ic_i) $$
using property (1) above. Should the correct statement therefore be that
$$ q\left( \sum_{i=1}^n c_i v_i \right) = \sum_{i,j=1}^n \frac{1}{2} a_{ij}c_ic_j? $$

You're right if $\mathbb F$ has characteristic different from 2.
When $\mathbb F$ has characteristic 2, then the statement is just false as written: there is a (non-unique) matrix $a_{ij}$ representing $q$ but it is not the matrix of $\psi$. The issue is, of course, that $2=0$, and so
$$
  \psi(v,v) = q(v+v) - q(v) - q(v) = q(0) - 0 = 0
$$
for all $v\in V$ regardless of the value of $q(v)$.
Instead, let's proceed directly. Let $w_j = \sum_{i=j}^nc_iv_i$. Noting that by applying (2) we get
$$
  q(\sum_{i=1}^nc_iv_i) = q(w_1) = q(c_1v_1+w_2) = \sum_{i=2}^nc_1c_i\psi(v_1,v_i) + c_1^2q(v_1) + q(w_2),
$$
we apply the same idea recursively to get
$$
   q(\sum_{i=1}^nc_iv_i) = \sum_{i=2}^nc_1c_i\psi(v_1,v_i) + c_1^2q(v_1) + \sum_{i=3}^nc_2c_i\psi(v_2,v_i) + c_2^2q(v_2) + \dotsb + \sum_{i=n-1}^nc_{n-1}c_i\psi(v_{n-1},v_i) + c_{n-1}^2q(v_{n-1}) + c_n^2q(v_n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{i<j\leq n}c_ic_j\psi(v_i,v_j) + \sum_{i=1}^nc_i^2q(v_i).
$$
This corresponds to the following matrix:
$$
  a = \begin{pmatrix}
    q(v_1) & \psi(v_1,v_2) & \psi(v_1,v_3) & \cdots & \psi(v_1,v_{n-1}) & \psi(v_1,v_n) \\
    0 & q(v_2) & \psi(v_2,v_3) & \psi(v_2,v_4) & \cdots & \psi(v_2,v_n) \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & q(v_n)
  \end{pmatrix}.
$$
This is the unique upper triangular matrix for $q$, but $a^T$ is also a valid matrix, as is any matrix obtained by transposing any number of entries individually. We see that
$$
  \psi(v,w) = (v+w)^Ta(v+w) - v^Tav - w^Taw = v^Taw + w^Tav
$$
so the matrix for $\psi$ is $a + a^T$.

I'm not going to delve as much into details as Nicholas did, I'm only going to point out that you might have misused the bilinearity. Indeed, let me use the bilinearity of the map $\psi(\cdot, \cdot)$ sequentially on a vector $v=c_i v^i$:
$$
\psi(c_i v^i, c_j v^j) = c_i \psi(v^i, c_j v^j) = c_i c_j \psi(v^i, v^j) = c_i c_j \big[ q(v^{i} + v^{j}) - q(v^{i}) - q(v^{j}) \big] \\ \underset{\text{using typical sum notation}}{=}
\sum_{i=1,\,j=1}^{n}c_i c_j \big[ q(v^{i} + v^{j}) - q(v^{i}) - q(v^{j}) \big] 
$$
Notice, how the sum inside the first $q$-term is not $2v^{i}$ or $2v^{j}$, since

those summing indices are independent,
$v^{i}$ and $v^{j}$ for $i\neq j$ are linearly independent since they are basis vectors.

If you introduce $a_{ij} = q(v^{i} + v^{j}) - q(v^{i}) - q(v^{j})$, you'll get what you want.

What I've done is use the definition $\psi_q(u,v) = q(u+v)-q(u)-q(v)$ for $u=v=\sum_{i=1}^n c_iv^i$. In this case, $\psi_q(u,u)=q(2u)-q(u)-q(u) = 2q(u)$. And yet your derivation seems fine. Am I missing something obvious?

I guess, you do. What you have done is basically defined an action of a quadratic form $q$ on a vector $u$, using a given bilinear form. That is a valid procedure — given any bilinear form $B$, you can construct a quadratic form $Q$ simply by the rule: $Q(x)=\frac{1}{2}B(x,x)$. That bilinear form is called an associated form. However your task is a tad subtler — you need to show, that that particular property is correct, regardless of how you define your $q(x)$ — via a bilinear form or by definition.
